# How can i save this data in my database? (Spring + Angular)

Tags: angular, spring

Good morning,

I've been taking a **Udemy** course from **FullStack** (Spring + Angular), whose author is **'Chad Derby'**. In this course, if the videos are followed, you can make a small ** ecommerce **.

The problem I have is that when it is given in **'Purchase'** to be able to carry out the order and in this way save the data in the base they are saved in a way that is not what I would like, to better graph this, I show these **images** of the data in the **base**:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlsXk.png

I would like to focus on the **'orders_item'** table, to achieve the structure of it, Chad Derby developed this entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_items")
@Getter
@Setter
public class OrderItem {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "image_url")
private String imageUrl;

@Column(name = "quantity")
private int quantity;

@Column(name = "unit_price")
private BigDecimal unitPrice;

@Column(name = "product_id")
private Long productId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
private Order order;
}
```

What I would like to do is make the table structure as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_items")
@Getter
@Setter
public class OrderItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "image_url")
    private String imageUrl;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private int quantity;

    @Column(name = "unit_price")
    private BigDecimal unitPrice;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private Order order;
    }
```

In this way the table in the database would be as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWwyz.png

I can place the order from the **backend**, using **Postman**. What I can't do is do it from the **frontend**. Next I will leave the logic:

Classes in **TypeScript** involved

```
export class Order {

    totalQuantity: number;
    totalPrice: number;
}

export class CartItem {

    id: string;
    name: string;
    imageUrl: string;
    unitPrice: number;

    quantity: number;

    constructor(product: Product) {
        this.id = product.id;
        this.name = product.name;
        this.imageUrl = product.imageUrl;
        this.unitPrice = product.unitPrice;
        this.quantity = 1;
    }
}

export class OrderItem {

    imageUrl: string;
    unitPrice: number;
    quantity: number;
    product: Product; // This property doesnt exist in the original project
    productId: string; // This property does exist in the original project

    constructor(cartItem: CartItem) {
        
      this.imageUrl = cartItem.imageUrl;
      this.quantity = cartItem.quantity;
      this.unitPrice = cartItem.unitPrice;
      this.productId = cartItem.id; // This mapping exists in the original project
      this.product.id = this.productId; // This assignment does not exist in the original project
    }
}
```

Now, the logic of the component **'Checkout'**:

```
onSubmit() {
    console.log("Handling the submit button");
    if (this.checkoutFormGroup.invalid) { 
      this.checkoutFormGroup.markAllAsTouched();
      return;
    }

    // Prepar an order
    let order = new Order();
    order.totalPrice = this.totalPrice;
    order.totalQuantity = this.totalQuantity;

    // Obtener los items del Carro.
    const cartItems = this.cartService.cartItems; // In the service, there is this property -> 
    cartItems: CartItem[] = [];
    

    // Create order items from our CartItem
    let orderItems: OrderItem[] = cartItems.map(tempCartItem => new OrderItem(tempCartItem));
    console.log(orderItems[0].productId); // I can access the value of the product that should be 
    save'.

    // Prepare the 'purchase'.
    let purchase = new Purchase();

    // Popular purchase - customer.
    purchase.customer = this.checkoutFormGroup.controls['customer'].value;

    // Popular purchase - shipping address.
    purchase.shippingAddress = this.checkoutFormGroup.controls['shippingAddress'].value;
    const shippingState: State = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(purchase.shippingAddress.state));
    const shippingCountry: Country = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(purchase.shippingAddress.country));
    purchase.shippingAddress.state = shippingState.name;
    purchase.shippingAddress.country = shippingCountry.name;

    // Popular purchase - billing address.
    purchase.billingAddress = this.checkoutFormGroup.controls['billingAddress'].value;
    const billingState: State = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(purchase.billingAddress.state));
    const billingCountry: Country = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(purchase.billingAddress.country));
    purchase.billingAddress.state = billingState.name;
    purchase.billingAddress.country = billingCountry.name;

    // Populate purchase - order and orderItems.
    purchase.order = order;
    purchase.orderItems = orderItems;

    // Call our API REST with the CheckoutService.
    this.checkoutService.placeOrder(purchase).subscribe(
      {
        next: response => {
          alert(`Your order has been received.\nOrder tracking number: 
          ${response.orderTrackingNumber}`)
          // Resetear el Carro.
          this.resetCart();
        },
        error: err => {
          alert(`There was an error: ${err.message}`);
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

When i click on **Submit** the error that throws me is  **'"ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined"'**.

From now on I am very grateful to anyone who can help me or guide me, if you need to see the **complete** **repository** I leave them below in the links:

**Backend** -> https://github.com/justanuser22/Backend

**Frontend** -> https://github.com/justanuser22/Frontend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
It seems to come from the `OrderItem` constructor:

    constructor(cartItem: CartItem) {
        
      this.imageUrl = cartItem.imageUrl;
      this.quantity = cartItem.quantity;
      this.unitPrice = cartItem.unitPrice;
      this.productId = cartItem.id; // This mapping exists in the original project
      this.product.id = this.productId; // This assignment does not exist in the original project
    }
```

In that scope, the `this.product` is `undefined` since it was never assigned. And `undefined` doesn't have an `id` property. We don't have your code for the 'Product` but try something along this lines:

```
constructor(cartItem: CartItem) {
    
  this.imageUrl = cartItem.imageUrl;
  this.quantity = cartItem.quantity;
  this.unitPrice = cartItem.unitPrice;
  this.productId = cartItem.id; // This mapping exists in the original project
  this.product = new Product();
  this.product.id = this.productId; // This assignment does not exist in the original project
}
```

Comment: I tried what you wrote and it worked, thank you very much!

Comment: Please mark the answer as a correct one then.